Existence of a function with certain properties, satisfying a functional equation
I came across the following problem.
Let $f(x)$ be a real-valued function defined on the real numbers. If $f(x)$ has five distinct roots and $f(5-x)=f(5+x)$, find the sum of the roots.
The problem itself is not that difficult, and kinda fun.
I wonder however if such a function even exists.
Originally the problem was published on brilliant.org. Having no clue how high their standards are in their choice of choosing problems (or any experience with the website at all), I slightly mistrust that this problem is well-stated, in terms of "Do such functions even exist?". Maybe this was not even attempted, as the problem is stated under the assumption of existence.
Is there a way to prove existence of a function like that?
Can you give an example?
I feel like that the somewhat periodic property and the condition that there are exactly five distinct roots should be(?) contradicting itself.
If I for example start with a root of $f$ for $x=0$,
I conclude from $f(5-5)=f(5+5)$ that $x=10$ is a root.
From $f(15-5)=f(5+15)$ I conclude that $x=20$ is a root, and so forth.
This should already show, that a function like that can not exist, as it does not matter where one of the roots lies.
Am I mistaken?
Thank you.

the problem is not, um, careful. For a smooth function it requires a double root at $5,$  so they are not counting multiplicity.


Thank you for your response.
